# Control ID is not accessible in user defined class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a querystring.aspx file having a gridview inside in it.

In querystring.cs file's default class that is

`public partial class querystring : System.Web.UI.Page`,

i can access the `gridview` control id.I have made a another class below this class ,but it is not accessing the `gridview` control id.

This is user defined class code in querystring.cs file:-

```
public partial class bindingmethod : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void show()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adb = new SqlDataAdapter("show_answers", con);
        adb.Fill(dt);

       GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    //Get a connection string to make a db connection
    public static string getconnectionstring()
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crudconnection1"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

For GridView1 it says:

```
The name GridView1 does not exist in the current context.
```

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Why did you create the `bindingmethod` class?

Comment: so that i could make a object of bindingmethod class and call its show() method inside static method of querystring class.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense, `bindingmethod` isn't a `System.Web.UI.Page` therefore I don't know why your inheriting from it. Also, the `Grid`/`GridView` are part of the `querystring` page therefore you will only be able to access them from that page.

I think what you want to do is move your `show`/`getconnectionstring` methods into your `querystring` class and get rid of `bindingmethod` altogether.

Comment: @user1627138 yep, I see your updated code but my answer remains the same.

Comment: i need to call show() method from static [webmethod].So can you please tell me solution for it.i will move show/getconnectionstring to the querystring class then.

Comment: i tried to acces it inside querystring class's static method  by making a instance of the querystring class,but the it is not being call.i checked it using breakpoints.it says:_
unreachable code detected.

Comment: @user1627138 you need to update your original question to say exactly what it is you are trying to do, right now it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx page on top has an attribute `Inherits="querystring"` in the page attributes. That is linking your aspx page to your code behind class `querystring`. Since you created a new class `bindingmethod`, it is in no way related to the `aspx` page. You can't inherit the aspx page from the multiple classes and the objects in the `aspx` page like `GridView1` is not visible to your new class in any manner.

I am not sure why are you creating a new class. It appears you just need another method in your `querystring` class and you need to call that method probably in `Page_Load` event.

Comment: actually i need to call a show() methods from static [webmethod].

Comment: Now thats a different question, which you may ask in a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass in a reference to the GridView to your new class/method.

From your querystring.cs class:

```
bindingmethod b = new bindingmethod();
b.show(this.GridView1);
```

BindingMethod.cs

```
public class bindingmethod 
{ 
    public void show(GridView gridView) 
    { 
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring()))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            using(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
              cmd.Connection = con; 
              con.Open(); 

              using(SqlDataAdapter adb = new SqlDataAdapter("show_answers", con))
              {
                  adb.Fill(dt); 

                  gridView.DataSource = dt; 

                  gridView.DataBind(); 
              }
           }
        }
    } 

    //Get a connection string to make a db connection 
    public static string getconnectionstring() 
    { 
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crudconnection1"].ConnectionString; 
    } 
}
```